# Javascript redirect to dynamic url issue in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a 'puzzle' route with a dynamic url depending on the puzzle number that is working without issue:

```
@app.route("/puzzle/<puzzle_id>")
@login_required
def puzzle(puzzle_id):
    some sqlalchemy queries
    return render_template('puzzle.html', other variables)
```

I tried to do the same thing with an attempt route but using jquery javascript in the html to redirect:

```
-(jquery function above here that worked fine without the redirect)-
}).done(function (response) {
    var attempt_num = response['attempt'];
    var urli = "{{ url_for('attempt', attempt_num=attempt_num) }}";
    console.log(urli)
    window.location.href = urli;
```

for route:

```
@app.route("/attempt/<attempt_num>")
@login_required
def attempt(attempt_num):
    some sqlalchemy queries to fill variables
    print("render attempt template with attempt = "+str(attempt.id),file=sys.stderr,flush=True)
    return render_template('attempt.html', other variables)
```

My print statement produces:

> render attempt template with attempt = 80

and the flask server shows:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2021 19:50:27] "←[37mGET /attempt/80?redir=True HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Mar/2021 19:50:27] "←[33mGET /attempt/ HTTP/1.1←[0m" 404 -

It looks like it is working correctly and trying to go to /attempt/80, but then it tries going to /attempt/ instead which isn't a defined route and causes a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional console log print statement and found that the {{ url_for  }} block wasn't appending the number properly. I don't understand why that part isn't working, but I was able to manually append the number to the url string before the redirect and it worked.